# ColdFusion variable with braces in it {}

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm dealing with a REST API where it returns an array of structures and some of the keys in the structure have names like this.

```
{custitem_webcategory#display}
```

So I am trying to access them in this manner

```
#InventoryJSON.items[1].["{custitem_webcategory#display}"]#
```

I just keep getting the following error.

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 205 at column 133.
> ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
> [

I've tried single quotes as well no luck. I have also tried escaping the `#` in the key with `##` and still no luck.

Comment: Close, but the syntax looks wrong. It using both dot notation AND structure notation for that last key.  Try removing the "."  just before it. ie  `InventoryJSON.items[1]["{custitem_webcategory##display}"]`

Comment: @SOS this is correct. I would mark it as the answer but I see no way to mark a comment as the answer. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Close, but the syntax looks wrong. It using both dot notation AND structure notation for that last key. Try removing the "." just before it. ie InventoryJSON.items[1]["{custitem_webcategory##display}"]

This answer in the commennts above by @SOS is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this because I wasn't aware that ColdFusion allowed struct keys to have the `#` symbol as part of the key.  So given that the `#` is ASCII 35, I would access your array of structs using the variable you have in question like this.

```
InventoryJSON.items[1].["custitem_webcategory#chr(35)#display"]
```